# Why doesn't the official StackExchange android app support chat?

Tags: feature-request, chat, android-app

Why doesnt the official SE android app support chat . It would be better to have an all in one app that wouldn't require us to rely on third party softwares or browsers. I came across a third party app that supports chat :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sudosaints.stackoverflow&hl=en

Personally ,i dont prefer using browsers on a mobile given that they aren't smooth enough compared to what a chat app would be like.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx